# Discuss Performance of Spring boot has large size

Tags: spring-boot

I am a rookie for using spring boot.
Now, i have some question to ask.
When i finish a server project by spring boot, and packaging the project as a war file.
I suppose the size of war file more than 4 gb.
Does the large war file affect system performance of Windows or Linux to increase response time of client?
Thanks everyone for reading.

Comment: Is there a reason why you assume, that the WAR file would be larger than 4 GB? If your concern is, that you want to include videos, images or other large files which would be provided to the users, then the answer is, that you should not include them in the WAR file, but rather on a separate file storage, which is then accessed by your application.

Comment: Actually my war file size is 58 MB include many jar in jar and many js file, like jquery. I have same opinion with you. Because i can not find related discussion about my question, so i post the question to know anyone's opinion. Thanks your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Zip format used for a WAR files has a limit of 4Gb so I suspect you can't have a WAR file that is bigger than 4GB. The performance hit of a large WAR file would likely be in container startup. A container will often extract the WAR during the startup process.

4 GB is not likely unless you are packaging a large amount of static data. The size of a recent reasonably size project I worked on which included an angular front end was around 70 MB packaged as a fat Jar (executable jar). It would likely be smaller if packaged as a war.

Comment: I review my war file which total size is 58.6 Mb, static resources size is 6 Mb, lib size is 49 Mb. Actually, i can reduce static resources by cdn. Thanks your answer.